# Polar equations

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Determine the points of intersection between the curves in polar coordinates:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}r=3\\r=4\sin(3\theta)\\r=-\dfrac{1}{\sin(\theta)}\end{array}\right.
$$

understand that I have to solve the systems of corresponding equations, but it generates a single value, I do not know how to generate the following points. And well, it is clear that I could do it by symmetry but formally / analytically can it be determined?

and one more question, to solve this integral
$$\int\sqrt{12\cos(3\theta)+16\sin^{2}(3\theta)}d\theta$$
to use the Weierstrass substitution would be adequate?

Answer (score 2):

HINT :

Draw the three curves and see the intersection points.

Computing the coordinates of each one is for you.

[image]